# React hooks form: reset or setValue when updating form first time from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am in a child component, which receives `customer` prop from its parent component.

So I want to update the form with values coming from `customer`, so I have done this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    if (isMounted) {
      reset({
        firstname: customer.firstname,
        lastname: customer.lastname,
        address: {
          street: customer.address.street,
          city: customer.address.city,
          country: customer.address.country,
        },
      });
    }

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
}, [customer, reset]);
```

but actually, I noticed that it's not changing properly the values inside the `address` nested object (`street` and `city` are updated, `country` is not).

However, if I am using `setValue`, it will update the value accordingly.
So my question is: which one between `reset()` and `setValue()` should be used for this specific case?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide live code example?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your use case you have to use `reset` and you're doing a correct thing there but may be the country dropdown/selector fall in the below mentioned case as per `react-hook-form` [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset). (Read the first line)

> For controlled components like React-Select which do not expose a ref prop, you will have to reset the input value manually with setValue or connect your component via useController or Controller.

I believe this piece of code is correct but the code example of form will help to understand the context in a much better way.